# PyQt UI event control segregation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am a beginner in python but my OOPS concept from Java and Android  are strong enough to motivate me in making some tool in python.
I am using PyQt for developing the application. In my application there are lot of QTabWidget used and has lot of UI controls in each TAB widget. Please see the screenshot for the same.
[image]

All of the event control of entire tool i have kept in one single file but now i want to segregate it based on one individual python file per QTab for event control inside the Tab.

My project file architecture looks like :

[image]

I know this would be some really easy thing but considering my experience with Python i am finding it difficult. I would really appreciate example with code snippet. Since i am able to control real complicated QThread from seperate files but not able get how to do it for Ui controls.

I tried making a file for it like i made for Thread classes but end up with argument passing expection to super

```
from generated.MainGUI import Ui_MainWindow
class SemiAuto_Create_Load(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=none):
        super(SemiAuto_Create_Load, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.connectControlEvents()
```

Tried : `self.sacl = SemiAuto_Create_Load()`

Exception :

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: There isn't really a question anywhere in your text, although the whole things looks more like a couple of problems to me. I guess, it would be good to break the problems down into different smaller ones and ask for each of them separately, highlighting the actual specific questions and if necessary delivering minimal, running examples showing the error.

Comment: @Trilarion Just got it working

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got this working with changes in

**`Mainwindow.py`**

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        Profile().notify(None)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.connectButtons()

        SemiAuto_Create_Load(self, self.ui)
```

And

**`SemiAuto_Create_Load`**

```
class SemiAuto_Create_Load(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, ui):
        super(SemiAuto_Create_Load, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = ui
        self.connectControlEvents()

    def connectControlEvents(self):
        self.ui.load_vsa_radio.clicked.connect(self.onLoad_vsa_radio)
        self.ui.create_vsa_radio.clicked.connect(self.onCreate_vsa_radio)
```

Problem was passing the parameter with parent in init() and trying to get the object of MainGUI directly instead of as a parameter from MainWindow